# Server program stuck in error while loop

Tags: java, serversocket

Here is my code for a simple server program,a client would connect and then a person object is created, even when there is no client trying to connect there is still the error.  P.S.  How do I printStackTrace(), I get red writing as opposed to a stack trace if I uncomment the line in the server in the second catch statement (in while loop).

```
'import java.net.ServerSocket;
 import java.net.Socket;


public class Test {

    ServerSocket ss;
    int id;

    public Test(int portNo){

        id = 0;
        Listen(portNo);
    } 

    private void Listen(int portNo){

        try{
            ss = new ServerSocket(portNo);
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());     
        }

        while(true){
            try{
                id++;
                new Thread(new Person(ss.accept(),id)).start();
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println("2 " + e.getMessage());
                //e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } 
    }

}
```

Whenever I run this I always get the error "2 null" repeating.

Person class:

```
import java.net.Socket;


    public class Person implements Runnable{

        int id;

        public Person(Socket s, int id){

            this.id = id;
        }

        public void run(){

            System.out.println(id + " Connected to server");

        } 

    }
```

Client code:

```
 import java.net.InetAddress;
 import java.net.Socket;
 import java.util.Scanner;


 public class test1{

    String serverIp;
    Boolean connected;
    InetAddress IP;
    Socket clientSocket;
    Integer clientID;
    int ssPortNo;

    public test1(){
        System.out.println("Enter IP : ");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String ip = sc.next();
        System.out.println("Enter port : ");
        String port = sc.next();
        setupConnection(ip, port);
    }




    private void setupConnection(String serverIP, String port) {
        int portInt = Integer.parseInt(port);
        serverIp = serverIP;
        try {
            connected = true;
            IP = InetAddress.getByName(serverIP);
            clientSocket = new Socket(serverIP, portInt);
            System.out.println("Connecting");
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("1 " + e.getMessage());  
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the error ? I tried to run the server without a client to connect and works fine ...

Comment: With e.getMesage I get 'null'.

Comment: I have also checked the above code. It does not give any error. So, please post the client's code.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you don't do anything if there is an exception.

> Whenever I run this I always get the error "2 null" repeating.

This is because (I think) you already have a server that listen to a specific port and you run a server in the same port. In this case is throwned an exception (Address already in use). To rapidly verify, try to change the port where the server listen.

**EDIT**

I think that for some reason your ServerSocket is null. Can you add this in your Server and show the output?

```
if(ss!=null){
        while(true){
            Socket socket = null;
            try{
                id++;
                System.out.println("Server wait at 9094");
                socket = ss.accept();
                new Thread(new Person(socket,id)).start();
                socket.close();
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println("2 " + e);
            }

        } 
    }
        else 
        {
            System.out.print("the ServerSocket is NULL");
        }
```

Comment: I tried what you did in the edit and it works i.e. the output is 1 connected to server, 2 connected to server etc.